# Como calcular a entropia de shannon baseada no cabeçalho HTTP

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, segurança

A entropia de Shannon é dada pela fórmula:

[image: Shannon]

Onde `Ti` será os dados extraídos do meu dump de rede (dump.pcap).

O fim de um cabeçalho HTTP em uma conexão normal é marcado por `\r\n\r\n`:
[image: header HTTP completo]

Exemplo de um cabeçalho HTTP incompleto (pode ser um ataque de negação de serviço):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu objetivo é calcular a entropia do número de pacotes com `\r\n\r\n` e sem `\r\n\r\n` afim de compará-las.

Eu posso ler o arquivo PCAP assim:

```
import pyshark

pkts = pyshark.FileCapture('dump.pcap')
```

A entropia baseada nos números de IP eu fiz:

```
import numpy as np
import collections

sample_ips = [
    "131.084.001.031",
    "131.084.001.031",
    "131.284.001.031",
    "131.284.001.031",
    "131.284.001.000",
]

C = collections.Counter(sample_ips)
counts = np.array(list(C.values()),dtype=float)
#counts  = np.array(C.values(),dtype=float)
prob    = counts/counts.sum()
shannon_entropy = (-prob*np.log2(prob)).sum()
print (shannon_entropy)
```

Alguma ideia? É possível/faz sentido calcular a entropia baseada no número de pacotes com `\r\n\r\n` e sem `\r\n\r\n`? Ou é algo que não faz sentido?
Alguma ideia de como fazer o cálculo?

O dump de rede está aqui: https://ufile.io/y5c7k

Algumas linhas dele:

[image: dump com filtro HTTP]

```
30  2017/246 11:20:00.304515    192.168.1.18    192.168.1.216   HTTP    339 GET / HTTP/1.1 


GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.216
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept: */*
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Connection: keep-alive
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu não sei como é a estrutura do seu pacote retornado pelo pyshark, mas imagino que ele tenha 2 informações, o endereço ip e o conteúdo do pacote. Imaginando que voce tenha essas 2 informacoes em um dict, voce poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
pkgs = [
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'content': 'Im a http header\r\n\r\n<html><body>',
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'content': 'Im a not a http header',
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'content': 'Im a http header\r\n\r\n<html><body>',
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'content': 'Im a not a http header',
    },
    {
        'ip': '127.0.0.2',
        'content': 'Im a not a http header too',
    }
]

def is_http(content):
    return '\r\n\r\n' in content

classified_pkgs = [(p['ip'], is_http(p['content'])) for p in pkgs]
>> [('127.0.0.1', True),
>> ('127.0.0.1', False),
>> ('127.0.0.2', True),
>> ('127.0.0.2', False),
>> ('127.0.0.2', False)]
```

Depois basta voce calcular as probabilidades como voce calculou antes:

```
import numpy as np
import collections

counter = collections.Counter(classified_pkgs)
counts  = np.array(list(counter.values()),dtype=float)

prob = counts/counts.sum()
shannon_entropy = (-prob * np.log2(prob)).sum()
print (shannon_entropy)
```

Comment: Eu disponibilizei o arquivo do dump de rede aqui:    https://ufile.io/y5c7k

Comment: não entendi como tirar estas informações do pacote a partir do dump...

Comment: @EdS seu link tem 53MB, cola algumas linhas na sua questão...

Comment: @MagicHat : o que você quer que eu extraia? Eu colo na questao!

Comment: Então, coloque um trecho do seu arquivo...

Comment: @MagicHat: editei. Esta bom? Obrigado! usei filtro http do wireshark!

Comment: Para ser sincero não está bom, vc está colocando a imagem coloca umas linhas do código do arquivo que estas a capturar algum dado...

Comment: @MagicHat: Melhorou? Colei uma linha da imagem. Precisa de mais?

Comment: @MagicHat: Você poderia ajudar?

Comment: @EdS para te ser sincero eu não entendi sua dúvida... https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha as vezes lá no chat fiuca mais fácil para entender

Comment: @MagicHat: eu nao sei como fazer a verificação da string "\r\n\r\n" para criar o contador: com_string e sem_string

Comment: @EdS mas isso não é exatamente o que essa resposta responde?

Comment: @MagicHat: eu leio o PCAP mas não entendi como verificar a string "na prática"!

Comment: @EdS eu acredito que vc tem de fazer um `parse` no seu pcap através de uma regex... Não vou poder ajudá-lo, agora pq num é tão simples, mas acho que se vc pesquisar sobre regex se consegue....